# hailstone sequence using recursion in python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, recursion, collatz-sequence

Douglas Hofstadter's Pulitzer-prize-winning book, Gödel, Escher, Bach, poses the following mathematical puzzle:

> - Pick a positive integer *n* as the start.
> - If *n* is even, divide it by 2.
> - If *n* is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1.
> - Continue this process until *n* is 1.
>
> The number *n* will travel up and down but eventually end at 1 (at
>   least for all numbers that have ever been tried -- nobody has ever
>   proved that the sequence will terminate). Analogously, hailstone
>   travels up and down in the atmosphere before eventually landing on
>   earth.
>
> The sequence of values of *n* is often called a Hailstone sequence,
>   because hailstones also travel up and down in the atmosphere before
>   falling to earth.

Does it make sense to implement using recursion? I wrote some bad solution below. Please correct me.

```
def hailstone(n):
    if(n<0):
        print("Invalid input")
        return 
    if(n==1):
        print(1)
        return 
    if(n%2 == 0):
        print(n)
        hailstone(n/2)
        return
    if(n%2==1):
        print(n)
        hailstone((n*3) + 1)
        return
```

How do I move the `n<0` condition to the right place?

Comment: This is also known as the [Collatz sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). And yes, it makes sense to use recursion - then you can memoize it for an easy "dynamic programming" approach.

Comment: @jonrsharpe (n < 0) condition makes it bad coding style, so can you help me refine the code logic?

Comment: What do you mean *"bad coding style"*? Where do you think *"a right place"* for `if(n<0):` would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a bit awkward, mostly due to:

1. Repetition;
2. Repetition; and
3. Doesn't follow [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) (specifically, e.g. `if(n<0):` should be `if n < 0:`.

A few comments:

```
def hailstone(n):
    if(n<0):
        print("Invalid input") # should be an exception
        return # don't need explicit return[ None]
    # what if n == 0?
    if(n==1):
        print(1) # same as print(n)
        return # see above 
    if(n%2 == 0): # n == 0 comes here and loops indefinitely
        print(n) # repeat
        hailstone(n/2)
        return # repeat
    if(n%2==1): # should just be else
        print(n) # repeat
        hailstone((n*3) + 1)
        return # repeat
```

An alternative, moving all the `print(n)` to the top and all the `return` (implicitly) to the bottom, would be:

```
def hailstone(n):
    """Print the terms of the 'hailstone sequence' from n to 1."""
    assert n > 0
    print(n)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        hailstone(n / 2) 
    elif n > 1:
        hailstone((n * 3) + 1)
```

Comment: we are printing the values whenever we enter into new localframe of a function, and then we are returning back with implicit `return None` which is at bottom of the function?

Comment: @overexchange that's right.